# Download list of videos with pytube

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I’m just at learning level of python so I don't know advanced level programming actually I use a pytube code for downloading YouTube videos,
It's great works just fine but if I have list.csv file which contains just urls of youtube videos in first column and rows above 200 I mean more than 200 video urls!
How do I put the file link to this code so that videos could be downloaded and I don't have to put every single url,

Code which I use is something like,

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=_XBVWlI8TsQ")
yt = yt.streams.filter(file_extension="mp4").get_highest_resolution()
yt.download('D:\')
print("done")
```

If anyone could help me here,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('list.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    urls = [row[0] for row in reader]
```

you can use a csv reader to collect urls to add them to a list then use a loop to download each element from the newly created list.

you need to also need to import csv to use csv reader.

Comment: I dont have my laptop right now so I checked it on my phone & I did

```from pytube import YouTube
import csv

yt = YouTube("urls")

with open('/storage/emulated/0/DLY/A/list.csv', newline=') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    urls = [row[0] for row in reader]

yt = yt.streams.filter(file_extension="mp4").get_by_resolution("360p")
yt.download('/storage/emulated/0/DLY/A/')
print("done")```

it didnt work
now I do have a very little knowledge of python so I cant figure what I did wrong! plz correct me!